# I am getting undefined after getting the actual output JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

**Each time when i run this code I get the output but with that output 
I also get undefined What does that undefined indicates**

```js
function factorial(num) {

  let final = 1;

  function helper(no) {
    if (no === 0) return;
    if (no > 1) {
      final *= no;
    }
    no--;
    helper(no);
  }
  helper(num);
  console.log(final);
}

factorial(5)
```

Comment: you mean there's `undefined` in the console ? It just means the function you call returns nothing.

Comment: It just logs an output value here, you may be getting `undefined` from the other code in your project environment

Answer (score 0):

Your factorial function doesn't return anything indeed.

You are doing a `console.log` to print the value, and the absence of "return" at the end is equivalent to having an implicit `return undefined`.

Your browser's console will output the return value of the function, that's why you may have been confused.

Use `return final` instead of (or in addition to) your `console.log(final);`

That would be preferred if you want your factorial function to actually *return* a value (that you could use later) instead of just printing it to the console.

Comment: Hey downvoters, indeed the answer was very wrong first, but I was editing it. Please see edit ;) thank you.

Comment: The `helper` function is being recursively called and it modifies the external value `final`, when it's finished it simply stops executing and this modifying `final`. A `return` statement (other to than to stop the execution)` is unneeded in this case. Although I agree that it's probably a good idea to have the recursive function be pure.

Comment: exactly. However, the factorial function is probably missing a return anyway. OP is probably just confused with the notion of return value of a function VS printing.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misread what you said. For some reason, I thought you were suggesting adding a `return` because without it the function doesn't work.